# jQuery rounded corners IE problem

Tags: jquery

I've tried http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/ and "curvyconvers", both with the same result. In ie7 & 8, my div is visible for about a second, without rounded corners, and then it dissapears. The div is 100x100px with a 1px black border.

Comment: accept some of ur prev questions first ^_^

Comment: Provide some code(markup). This info is quite insufficient, we can`t see what you have done and what is the error.

Comment: Never mind, something with the border messed the script up. When i removed the border and added backgroundcolor, it worked ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too have realized jquery corner limitation in ie. But the curvycorners works well in all the browsers.

Have a look here http://www.belanr.cz/skola/formular/js/rohy/examples/demo2.html It works well in all browser with borders.

Can you share your code.